# C++: Is it possible to template a typename?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I write:

```
template<typename X>
typename Namespace::Something<X> S;
```

And then I template a function as follows:

```
template<typename X>
void my_function(X input){
    S<X> y = S<X>(input);
}
```

Is this possible? What would be the syntax to do it if it is possible?

Answer (score 11):

You can use an [*alias template declaration*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias):

```
template <typename X>
using S = Namespace::Something<X>;
```